# Allowing a user to type "-999" to quit the console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application

in new to C# and I was wondering how could I allow the user to type -999 to quit the application. I'm using visual studios 2015 and I'm working on a console application, I thought something like this would work

```
        string userInput;
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userInput == "-999")
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

but I was wrong, Is there a way to do something similar to this? thanks.

Comment: What happened when you debugged it? It *should* work, you will need to post more code.

Comment: You may simply use the return statement. Returning from the main function triggers exit.

Comment: Or use `Environment.Exit(exitcode)` to close the program, since Application.Exit is only for Windows Forms, not for console applications.

Comment: Hmm.. Application is `System.Windows.Forms' method. and.. Console is not Windows.Forms What is your application, console or winform?

Comment: On a usability note, what's wrong with having the user type "quit" if he wants to quit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application.Exit();`method is a part of the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, thus it cannot be used in console applications (if your project specified as such). So you shall either just return if your code is in the `Main` void of your console application, or use `Environment.Exit(exitcode)` with the appropriate exit code. Make sure your project is a console application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project has "Console application" in the output type configuration. If you have set it as a Windows Application, Console.ReadLine won't read anything and will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Or `return;` if you are the Main(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment.Exit(). You can pass exit code -1 for error or 1 for success. Code will be received by underlying os. Hope it helps.